# What does this bizarre message mean which popped up in Windows 10 days after I installed it?

Tags: windows-10

> Let's finish setting up
>
> Now that you're connected to the network you aren't able to finish
>   setting up your device.
>
> [OK]

No, I did not make any typos in the above quote. See for yourself:

[image: proof]

Am I hallucinating? Have I gone insane? Am I reading this correctly? What on Earth could it possibly mean? I seriously don't even have a guess. It says that because I'm now "connected to the network" (which I have been for days for this VM), I'm ***NOT*** "able to finish setting up my device"?

Huh? I've read the message numerous times now and it's still reading like word salad to me.

I'm dead serious about not having a clue what they are talking about.

Comment: Open Control Panel, Device Manager and see if any devices have red or yellow exclamation marks (not set up).  Check that your printer (and scanner) are both working properly.

Comment: Please list the medications you are taking ;-). Yeah I have a collection of crazy windows dialog. Adding this one to it, thanks.

Comment: Seems to me like a typo by the Windows team. It probably meant to say "are able" not "aren't able". And because this doesn't seem like a very common message, Microsoft either doesn't know about it or hasn't deemed it important enough to push an update for yet.

Comment: Please open a Command Prompt and do `ver` then copy the result, come back here, click [edit], and paste the result into your question.